# How to continue on error a call to an executable using &$var

Tags: powershell

Let's say I want to *continue on error* when executable is called using `&`. Example:

`&$executable`

Is there any way I could get this?

Comment: $erroractionpreference?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Yeah, but `&$executable -erroraction silentlycontinue` won't work because the parameter is being passed to the executable...

Comment: Ah, I see.... .

Comment: there's a global variable called `$erroractionpreference`

Comment: @4c74356b41 Yeah, now I undestood it...

Comment: well, i wasn't creating an answer, as I assumed you've tried that one ;)

Comment: @4c74356b41 Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `$ErrorActionPreference` Global Variable to one of this options:

SilentlyContinue, Stop, Continue, Inquire, Ignore

For example:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
&$executable
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a function for that to reset the old `ErrorActionPreference`:

```
function Invoke-MyFunctorSilently 
{
    param
    (
        [scriptblock]$func
    )

    $currentEa = $ErrorActionPreference
    try
    {
        $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
        $func.Invoke()
    }
    finally
    {
        $ErrorActionPreference = $currentEa
    }
}
```

So you can invoke it like this:

```
Invoke-MyFunctorSilently -func { & calc.exe}
```